# MySQL wont start after modifying /etc/my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have Linux Red Hat 5, with Zend Server and MySQL Server installed.

I am trying to change the default MySQL port to 512.  However, after making this change, MySQL will no longer startup.  I get the error below:

```
Starting MySQL...The server quit without updating PID file 
    (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: try delete the pid file.

Comment: i have tried to delete it and restart mysql again. and i have got the same error message.

Comment: Use 'tail' to view error log to identify problems during start up. At your RedHat bash shell type:
 service mysql start ; tail -f /var/lib/mysql/error.log 
Or whatever your path to the error log is.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you are trying to change the MySQL port from 3306 to 512.  If that is correct, then then problem is that all *nix (Linux, Solaris, AIX, etc) require you to run as root in order to bind to ports below 1024.

Try running it on port 3307 or something.

Comment: I have logined as root account. 
I have changed the port to 1433, then restart linux.
I am still got the error Starting MySQL...The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.MySQL.pid).

Comment: Please post your my.cnf.  Is there anything else in the error log?